# No element exist

Tags: qt, automation, frameworks, pywinauto

I'm trying to **automate** the Telegram Application on window with pywinauto, I want to click the button Start Messaging like the image below[image]

**However**, when I try to inspect the element, it doesn't so any name, but still exists,
As I can see, this application belongs to Qt framework
[image]